# How can I receive payments from my nopCommerce shop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nopcommerce

I am evaluating the `nopcommerce` open source solution.

The setup was incredibly easy. The shop was up and running (Local server, for now!)
But then I am confused. 
When the user will purchase a product from my shop, how will I receive the payment?

I searched a lot in order to setup my credit card/accounnt/paypal information in the Admin area, but I couldnt find anything...

Can some one please help me with this?

Comment: Try asking @ http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to sign up with a 3rd party who takes the payment and then transfers the money into your account. You then enter the details provided by the 3rd party into the relevant settings under Administration -> Configuration -> Payment -> Payment Information. If there are not relevant settings you can write your own payment provider for the payment gateway of your choice.

Comment: Thanks. however, I have decided to move away from nopCommerce. I tried FastSpring and it seems great, mostly would go with them.

Answer (score 1):

Check Administration -> Configuration -> Payment -> Payment Information

Comment: I did, but where do you specify the account where the money goes to specially for a bank account or a credit card ?

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 things: a "payment gateway" and an "online merchant account"

- The payment gateway is a third party system that transfers the money from (usually) an HTML form to your bank account.
- The online merchant account is requested by your bank in order to receive online payments. You will normally deal with your bank to obtain one. One exception to this rule, is Paypal, which is a payment gateway and also acts as a bank, therefore it handles everything for you.

The most common payment gateways are: Worldpay, PayPoint, SagePay, Authorize.Net, and many others. It is different in every country.

Once you have chosen your Payment Gateway, you set up NopCommerce to integrate with it to display a form, sometimes an iframe, or a redirection. If NopCommerce does not support your payment gateway, you can download one from a third party or get someone to develop it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have used 2checkout as they are an existing payment provider.

Answer (score 0):

nopCommerce has a plugin Architecture, that allows you to create the code for a specific vendor (Merchant processor) They have several European vendors already built, you just download them and install.  It comes with Authorize.net plugin already, if you choose them, you up and running in a matter of minutes.  Look under DOCS" on the nopCommerce website for more info on creating a plugin, its not hard if your a .NET programmer.  I am going to dump my Merchant for Authorize.net just because its easier, and they all do the same thing, accept the cc and transfer the money to you for a fee, and basically they are pretty much all the same, unless your doing a risky business (porn) then you have to find a merchant who will accept those types of charges (normally at a higher rate)